# IIPImage derivative generation and caching

Tags: caching, memcached, squid

My client has a large number of images on its website. Each of these images has several derivatives, such as small, large, thumbnail, etc.

So far we have been generating static derivatives for each image, which in my opinion generates a lot of redundant data and makes their management harder.

I have been considering using an IIPImage server to generate derivatives on demand from one "web master" image. The advantages would be that I can just create one JPEG2000 image for all the derivatives, and I can use tiles for larger images using the same route. I can also take advantage of the [IIIF framework](http://iiif.io) to retrieve derivatives.

My main concern is caching the derivatives. I know IIP comes with Memcached support, but an in-memory store does not seem appropriate to cache derivatives for hundreds of thousands of images. An alternative I have thought of may be a Squid proxy. I have little experience with both caching approaches, so I could use some help here.

Is this the right direction to go, or is there a better solution, or should I stick to the current static derivative approach?

Thanks,

gm

Answer (score 0):

I think IIP Image would be a very good solution for your situation, mainly because the advantages you will get from the dynamic generation of images at various sizes from one master image.

Additionally, if you were to change an image, you would only have to swap the master and IIP would take care of the rest.

As for caching, I have used Varnish in front of IIP image very successfully on production sites. You could even use it in combination with the built in memcached support if you wanted to. It's quite straightforward to set up and configure.